# how to use epoll on tornado

Tags: linux, python-3.x, tornado, epoll

i am trying to make epoll work on tornado

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
from tornado.platform.epoll import EPollIOLoop
from tornado import web, gen

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @web.asynchronous
    @gen.engine    
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    EPollIOLoop().start()
```

but when i start the program and visit the url localhost:8888/ it didn't return anything.
is that my system didn't meet the requirement?my linux version was Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()`. It choose best IOLoop for your platform.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    ioloop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
    print ioloop # prints  <tornado.platform.epoll.EPollIOLoop object at ..>
    ioloop.start()
```

You should call `self.finish()` if you use [`asynchronous`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.asynchronous) decorator:

> If this decorator is given, the response is not finished when the
>   method returns. It is up to the request handler to call **self.finish()**
>   to finish the HTTP request. Without this decorator, the request is
>   automatically finished when the get() or post() method returns.

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @web.asynchronous
    @gen.engine    
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")
        self.finish()
```